# CSS: Text color slightly offset in Safari/Firefox

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox, safari

I'm having a strange problem with a website I'm building for a client.  I have some links in a list as part of a table, and in my CSS I have the following:

`a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DB6633;
}`

Which changes the link to orange when the mouse hovers over it.  This works fine on my 3 Macs using Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc (and my Windows PC using the same).  However when viewed on my clients browsers (Safari & Firefox on OS X 10.6.4) they see this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

etc.  As you can see, the orange doesn't line up with the text properly.  I haven't seen this before, and I can't reproduce it at my end.  I'm also having a problem with some images being slightly out also, but I'm not sure if that is related.

The client is running the latest versions of Safari & Firefox (as am I).  They are running OS X 10.6.4, but I have that on one of my laptops and it displays the site fine.

Has anyone seen this before, and if so how can I fix this?

** EDIT **

OK some more detail: it happens less in Firefox than in Safari.  I'm going to try and get it down to the least amount of code to reproduce it then I'll update with that also.

I think it's telling that it appears on both Firefox & Safari - which use different rendering engines.  Could it be system related?  An accessibility setting perhaps?

Comment: Did they increase the browser font size with ctrl +

Comment: Don't think so.  I have tried that at my end and it makes no difference, I still don't see any glitches.

Comment: I've never seen this before, but it's not surprising that these weird anomalies always seem to happen only client computers :S

Comment: It's a long shot but do you have a reset.css included to make sure there are no lingering styles? A good one we're using is http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: This is really weird. I have tried everything and I can't produce that. The only thing I can think of is that your client's screen might be playing tricks. Does this happen on other sites as well? If yes, then there could be a graphics issue on the computer or the screen is dying.

Comment: some weird artifact of antialiasing the font?

Comment: Can you link to actual code, or post on JSFiddle? You're asking for a lot of assumptions, plus it'd be especially interesting if someone here could _also_ reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is that a custom font? If you embedded via font-face, then the problem could be in the web font files, but you're not seeing them because you have the real font installed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the browser negating to compute exact glyph bounds (Done for the sake of performance.)

**The solution to this problem is to add a single line of text into your CSS:**

```
text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
```

this line can be added to the CSS of the div that requires it, and that way there's no extra processing done to the rest of the page.